# LabVIEW: How can I register on a callback from a CDLL

Tags: delphi, labview

The header file is the following:

```
#ifndef __EVTest_h_
#define __EVTest_h_
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)

// Typedefs ------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma pack (push,1)

/// <summary>
///   Callback called by Test
/// </summary>
/// <param name="B">
///   Simple counter
/// </param>
typedef void (__cdecl *TEVCallback)(uint8_t B);

#pragma pack (pop)

// Functions ------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/// <summary>
///   Tests calling a simple callback
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Callback">
///   Address of the callback procedure caled, which gets a 1-Byte parameter
///   passed when called.
/// </param>
DLLIMPORT void __cdecl Test(TEVCallback Callback);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif //#ifndef __EVTest_h_
```

I want a callback to trigger an event or something like that in Labview.
I managed to do it successfully with with a reference "LVUserEventRef" and the PostLVUserEvent. However, this is not possible in a DLL written in Delphi.

[image: Labview Event from DLL]

```
int32_t __declspec(dllexport)
TEST(LVUserEventRef* rwer)
{
    int32_t para = 200;
    Sleep(1000);
    PostLVUserEvent(*rwer, (void*)&para);
    return 0;
}
```

In Labview there is an extra tab in the "Call Library Function" VI, but I can't find anywhere how to use the callback.

[image: Callback Call Library Function]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible.  You would need to wrap the DLL which exposes the C-style callback into a wrapper DLL that registers the callback and itself generates a labview user event.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Do I need to build the wrapper dll in C++ or what?

Comment: Anything you like, it doesn't matter.

Comment: And I need to register the user event as I showed above?

Comment: Yes, the wrapper DLL must handle the callback and translate that to a labview user event, like what you've shown in your example above.

Comment: Oh. That is a lot of work. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: To clarify again: I have to build another one around the actual DLL?
Is that possible?
And in which programming languages ​​does the wrapper have to be built?

Comment: Yes.  Yes. And, it doesn't matter - pick your favourite language.  It must be able to consume a C DLL and produce a DLL which exposes a labview user event.  The wrapper DLL must register for the callback, process it, extract whatever data you want, and then communicate that data to LabView by packaging it into a user event.

Comment: @J... is correct; but an example may help.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and scoured the LabVIEW forums for an example without success, so I thought it might help to share how I implemented this.  Following the official advice from NI given [here](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P8XJSA0&l=en-GB), my LabVIEW VI looks like this:

[image]

The VI sets up the User Event, which expects to receive a cluster containing three integers and an array of bytes (`uInt8`).  It then calls the external DLL function `configRaiseLabviewRawDataUserEvent()`, passing it an app-specific ID (`uInt32`) and the ID of the user event (`LVUserEventRef`).  Then it waits for the DLL to raise the event by calling `PostLVUserEvent()`.

The DLL functions are as follows. `configRaiseLabviewRawDataUserEvent()` stores the user event ID and registers an internal call-back function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool configRaiseLabviewRawDataUserEvent( hMstkHandle uiConnectionHandle, LVUserEventRef labviewRawDataUserEventId )
{
  cout << "configRaiseLabviewRawDataUserEvent ..." << endl;
  // Store LabVIEW User Event ID for use in the call-back function (defined below).
  lvRawDataUserEventId = labviewRawDataUserEventId;
  cout << "LabVIEW User Event ID: " << labviewRawDataUserEventId << endl;
  // Register internal call-back function.
  return configRawDataCallback( uiConnectionHandle, labviewInternalRawDataCallback );
}
```

The internal call-back function `labviewInternalRawDataCallback()` calls `PostLVUserEvent()` with the user event ID and a pointer to a `struct` that corresponds to the LabVIEW cluster:

```
// Static variable to keep track of the LabVIEW User Event ID passed in.
static LVUserEventRef lvRawDataUserEventId;
// Struct to hold values to return to LabVIEW (to match the LabVIEW "cluster" that will receive them).
#pragma pack(1) // sets packing size to 1 for following structures, as required by LabVIEW: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019YsYSAU&l=en-GB
struct sLvRawDataCluster {
  hMstkHandle uiConnectionHandle;
  int iChannel;
  int iNumValues;
  uint8_t auiValues[ MAX_TCP_DATA_BYTES ];
};
#pragma pack() // returns packing size to that specified in command line options
// Declare static instance of LabVIEW struct for use in successive call-backs.
static sLvRawDataCluster lvData;

// Internal call-back to receive raw measurement data and then immediately send it to LabVIEW by raising the User Event
// associated with the ID passed in.
void __stdcall labviewInternalRawDataCallback( hMstkHandle uiConnectionHandle, int iChannel, int iNumValues, UINT8* auiValues )
{
  // Copy the raw data to a structure to pass to LabVIEW.
  lvData.uiConnectionHandle = uiConnectionHandle;
  lvData.iChannel = iChannel;
  lvData.iNumValues = iNumValues;
  memcpy( lvData.auiValues, auiValues, iNumValues * sizeof(UINT8) );
  // Send the address of the structure to LabVIEW.
  MgErr mgErr = PostLVUserEvent(lvRawDataUserEventId, &lvData);
  if ( mgErr != mgNoErr )
  {
    cout << "labviewInternalRawDataCallback: LabVIEW function PostLVUserEvent() failed with error code " << mgErr << endl;
  }
}
```

The LabVIEW user event is raised each time the internal call-back function is called, and the data is successfully passed from the DLL to LabVIEW.  (I had a few problems with the LabVIEW VI initially but [the NI community were very helpful](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Call-to-PostLVUserEvent-from-external-code-always-returns-an/m-p/4314854).)

Comment: I forgot to say that my example, in particular the use of `#pragma pack()`, is specific to a *32-bit Windows platform*, as that's what we use.  A better, cross-platform way of doing this would be to use `#include “lv_prolog.h”` and `#include “lv_epilog.h”` around the LabVIEW-compatible structure declarations.